# Formatting Book Heading Memoir Class

Tags: memoir, books

How could I remove the “Book 1” from the following. I am using "\book{Set Theory}" in the memoir class.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu98T.png)

I cannot use “\book*{Set Theory}” because I want it to appear in the Table of Contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine the macros for printing the book name and number, as (somewhat) explained in the [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) on page 81.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\printbookname}{}
\renewcommand{\printbooknum}{}
\tableofcontents
\book{Set theory}
\end{document}
```